# Fourier transformation

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm writing currently a program in Matlab which is related on image hashing. Loading the image and performing a simple down-sampling was not a problem.Here is my code

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
%%load Image
I = im2single(imread('cameraman.tif')); 
%%Perform filtering and downsampling
gaussPyramid = vision.Pyramid('PyramidLevel', 2);                 
J = step(gaussPyramid, I); %%Preprocessed Image
%%Get 2D Fourier Transform of Input Image
Y = fft2(I); %%fft of input image
```

The algorithm next assumes that 2D Fourier Transform ( Y in my case ) must be in the form `Y(f_x,f_y)` where `f_x,f_y` are the normalized spatial frequencies
in the range [0, 1].I'm not able to transform the output of fft2 function from Matlab  as it is required by the algorithm.

Comment: I was a little confused by Y(f_x,f_y), does that mean the input should be a size of (Y x 2) ? Or are x,y your coordinate system?

Comment: As described in the algorithm x and y are the coordinate system.More exactly image is described as i(x,y) .

Comment: The edited title was actually better than what you've got now. Capslock is in no way more legible or understandable.

Comment: Then I think you can just take the magnitude response, i.e. abs(Y) and normalize it by something like Y./ max(max(Y)).

Comment: It seems that this is the logical approach . Thank you !

Comment: What @GameOfThrows suggested is to normalize `Y`, but it sounds to me like you are asking how to find where inside of `Y` a given frequency component occurs. E.g., what is `Y(.25, .75)`? This is something different. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Tokkot I think that GameOfThrows approach is more about what describes the algorithm.The algorithm I want to implement describes preprocessing stage as follow _"Consider an image i(x, y) and its 2D Fourier transform
I(fx, fy), where fx and fy are the normalized spatial frequencies
in the range [0, 1]." _  . The next step in algorithm is to transform the output in polar coordinates . Certainly what Tokkot says is different but I guess is not what I need .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the paper in question (Multimedia Forensic Analysis via Intrinsic and Extrinsic Fingerprints by Ashwin Swaminathan) and found

> We take a Fourier transform on the preprocessed image
>   to obtain I(fx, fy).  The Fourier transform output is converted into polar co-ordinates to arrive at I′(ρ, θ)

By this, they seem to mean that I(fx, fy) is the Fourier transformation of the image. But they're trying to use the Fourier-Mellin transformation, which is different from a simple fft2 on the image. Based on the information [found in this set of slides](http://lapt.ece.northwestern.edu/files/mellin_transform_correlator.pdf),

> If an input image is expressed in terms of coordinates that are natural logarithms of the original coordinates, then the magnitude of its FT is insensitive to any change in scale of the original image (since it is Mellin Transform in the original coordinates)

and in files on the MATLAB Central File exchange, you have to do additional work to get the Mellin-Fourier transform; particularly, taking the magnitude (which appears to be your missing step), converting the coordinates to log polar and taking a second fft2. It's unclear to me why the *log* of log polar coordinates was omitted from the paper in the steps required. See [an implementation for image registration here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19731-fourier-mellin-image-registration) for an example. Note that this code is old, and the transformImage method appears not to exist; it does the log polar transform.